# How to make textboxes width dynamically like buttons in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have textboxes with some textblocks above it.

I want my application to have resizable width (not height) so I have setted only *MinWidth* for window. So when I click on right or left border of window I can scale it however I want.

My problem is, that when I use textboxes I don't get result what I would like to have.

If I position textboxes with textblock above it on *MinWidth* of window, after making the window bigger those textboxes will stay with same width on the same place according to ColumnDefinitions.

It does make sence since those textboxes have fixed width setted on 160 but if I try same thing with buttons according same columndefinitions and stuff those buttons gonna stretch according window size and it will be sorted by columndefintions.

Is there way how to acomplish same thing with textboxes? So when I stretch window from 1050px to full size 1920px mine textboxes would change width so it can be dynamically? *Width="Auto"* doesn't solve it for me

Adding images below so you can imagine it better hopefully.

xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="App.NewUI.Textboxes"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App.NewUI"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="720" MaxHeight="720" d:DesignWidth="1050">
<Border Padding="10">
    <StackPanel>

        <!-- TextBoxes + update button -->
        <Grid Margin="0 5 0 0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBox x:Name="txtBoxFirstname" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Firstname, ElementName=dg}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="160"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtBoxLastname" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Lastname, ElementName=dg}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="160"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtBoxTelephone" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Telephone, ElementName=dg}" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="160"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtBoxBorn" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Born, ElementName=dg}" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="160"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtBoxCategory" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Category, ElementName=dg}" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="160"/>

            <Button x:Name="btnUpdateRecord" Content="Update Record" Grid.Column="5" Click="btnUpdateRecord_Click"/>

        </Grid>

        <!-- datagrid -->
        <Grid Margin="0 15 0 0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <DataGrid x:Name="dg" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,-350" Width="auto" Height="350"/>
        </Grid>

    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

I've tried to set textboxes width to auto but then textboxes will be tiny without text and won't stretch anyway. Thank you for any tip

[Imgur images of window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbaCg.jpg)

Comment: Set the horizontal aligment to stretch

Comment: @NawedNabiZada *What is the reason for the two Grids* I think that this is better way than setting position of objects by margin

Comment: @NawedNabiZada and no, setting stretch for horizontal alignment does not working

Comment: You have set the Width to a fixed size = 160 ?!?

Comment: Oh I see now. @NawedNabiZada thank you. That didn't come in my mind.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, but if you remove the Width and set HorizontalAligment="Stretch" those textboxes will resize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleting fixed width and set *horizontal alignment* to *strech* figured it out.

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtBoxFirstname" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Firstname, ElementName=dg}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```